# Improve complexity of binary search counting number of higher and lower elements?

Tags: java, algorithm

Java Array's has a `binarySearch` method which returns an index of a given key in an array. However, if there are duplicates this binarySearch *does not guarantee which element will be found*

Example:

- An array of digits is given `[5 8 7 2 4 3 7 9 1 9]`.
- Sort this array `[1 2 3 4 5 7 7 8 9 9]`.
- Perform binary search on it with a given key.
- For each index returned, print the number of elements lower and higher than it.

For key `7`, index `5` is given - Number of smaller elements will be "5" and greater will be "3", since there are 2 `7`.

For key '0', index '-1' will be given since there are no elements smaller than it. `Smaller: 0, Greater: 10.`

For key '100', index '-11' will be given since there are no elements greater than it. `Smaller: 10, Greater: 0.`

For key '6', index '-6' will be given. Element does not exist in the array. `Smaller: 5, Greater: 5.`

Algorithm:

```
public class Counting {
    private void run() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int no_digits = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        int[] digits = new int[no_digits];
        for (int i = 0; i < no_digits; i++) {
            digits[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        sc.nextLine();
        Arrays.sort(digits);

        int no_queries = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < no_queries; i++) {
            int key = sc.nextInt();
            int upper = 0;
            int lower = Arrays.binarySearch(digits, key);

            if(lower == -1){
                lower = 0;
                upper = no_digits;
            }else if(Math.abs(lower) > no_digits){
                lower = no_digits;
                upper = 0;
            }else if(lower <= 0){
                lower = Math.abs(lower) - 1;
                upper = no_digits - lower;
            } else {
                int value = digits[lower];
                int j = 0;
                int k = 0;

               high: while(digits[lower + j] == value){
                    j++;
                    if((lower + j) > no_digits - 1){
                        break high;
                    }
                }

                upper = no_digits - lower - j;

                low: while(digits[lower - k] == value){
                    k++;
                    if((lower - k) < 0){
                        break low;
                    }
                }

                lower = lower - k + 1;

            }
            System.out.println("Smaller: " + lower + ", Greater: " + upper);
        }
        sc.close();      
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Counting newCounting = new Counting();
        newCounting.run();
    }
}
```

This works, however one of the test case has the algorithm traversing along the array from the head to the tail many times which causes the algorithm to take a fair bit of time to complete.

Example: An array of 100 digits of where the first half of the digits are `1` and the second half `100`.

If i search for `1`, the index might return `34` since there's no guarantee which index will be found. My algorithm will then traverse the array both way from index `34` only to get `Smaller: 0, Greater: 50`, since the top half of the arrays are all digit `100`.

Is there a way to make this more efficient? I am aiming for `O((N+Q) log N)` complexity where `Q` is the number of queries and `K` is the number of integers in the array.

Comment: Are you only restricted to use binary search or other algorithms as well?

Comment: Other algorithms are fine as well.

Comment: I don't see your primary goal. Are you aware about `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` kinds of binary search (names from C++STL, but approach and implementations are available elsewhere)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you could use `Map` for coutning elements and `TreeMap` for sorting ones. Bor big data, it is better to precalculate some data and then use it for your goal. This is approximate example of this idea:

```
public class Counting {
    private static NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> read(Scanner scan, int no_digits) {
        // put keys in the reverce order; key - digit, value - times in input
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>((key1, key2) -> Integer.compare(key2, key1));

        for (int i = 0; i < no_digits; i++) {
            int digit = scan.nextInt();
            map.put(digit, map.getOrDefault(digit, 0) + 1);
        }

        return map;
    }

    private static int[] calculate(int key, NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> map, int no_digits) {
        int lower = 0;
        int upper = no_digits;

        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            // for existed keys, get tail of reverce and get first element
            lower = map.tailMap(key, false).firstEntry().getKey();
            // for existed keys, get actual count and increment it
            upper = map.getOrDefault(key, -1) + 1;
        }

        return new int[] { lower, upper };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int no_digits = scan.nextInt();
            NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> map = read(scan, no_digits);
            int no_queries = scan.nextInt();

            for (int i = 0; i < no_queries; i++) {
                int[] res = calculate(scan.nextInt(), map, no_digits);
                System.out.println("Smaller: " + res[0] + ", Greater: " + res[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```